# Netty, option() vs childOption()?

Tags: server, config, netty

I have a question.

What time must use .option() and what time must use .childOption()?

I have a server.

I setup server by below lines. it is correct?

```
.option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, defaultConnectionBacklog);
.option(ChannelOption.SO_REUSEADDR, true);
.option(ChannelOption.ALLOCATOR, PooledByteBufAllocator.DEFAULT);


.childOption(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true);
.childOption(ChannelOption.SO_REUSEADDR, true);
.childOption(ChannelOption.TCP_NODELAY, true);
.childOption(ChannelOption.ALLOCATOR, PooledByteBufAllocator.DEFAULT);
```

Answer (score 2):

when you start a server:

`option` is used by XXXServerSocketChannel(e.g. `NioServerSocketChannel`)

`childOption` is used by the channel accpted by this ServerChannel

when you start a client:

you can only use `option`, because there's no child channel exsited.

so in your question,`.childOption(ChannelOption.SO_REUSEADDR, true);` is useless in the accepted Channel

for more detail, you can read the method `channelRead` in `ServerBootstrapAcceptor` class, the code is what to do when a ServerChannel accept a Channel.

P.S. `ServerBootstrapAcceptor` is the default handler in a ServerChannel pipeline.